# How do I use git-push --mirror with git-shell in SSH?

Tags: ssh, git, mirror, hook

I am attempting to setup a mirror-to-backup hook in our repositories. The hook is executing a `git push --mirror backup@server:path/foo.git`. However it fails stating:

```
fatal: What do you think I am? A shell?
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My `.ssh/authorized_keys` file has the following entry:

```
command="/path/to/git-shell" ssh-rsa ....

# no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty
# these are all set i just removed them for brevity.
```

I've tried various combinations but the git-shell documentation is exceedingly sparse. I'm not sure what the problem is I'm hoping someone here could point me in the right direction. What is causing this error? I was under the impression that git-shell was intended to be used with push/pull. Clearly, I must be missing something but I haven't a clue what it is.

The path on the backup server is to a set up bare repository.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you've set up a command in the `authorized_keys` file, but `man sshd`'s section on the authorized_keys file format clearly states:

> **command="command"**
>   Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is used for authentication.  The command supplied by the user (if any) is ignored. (…)

This means that whenever `git-upload-pack` attempts to contact `git-receive-pack` (by way of an `ssh` command including the call for `git-receive-pack`, it will be squashed in favour of the command specified in `.ssh/authorized_keys`.
`git-shell` can and does accept inbound git-related communications, but because the paramaters from `git-upload-pack` got squashed to null, the former is assuming that someone is trying to open an ordinary terminal, and cuts it off. This is explained in `man git-shell`:

> **name**
>          git-shell - Restricted login shell for Git-only SSH access
>   **synopsis**
>          git shell [-c  ]
>   **description**
>          A login shell for SSH accounts to provide restricted Git access. When
>          -c is given, the program executes  non-interactively;
>           can be one of git receive-pack, git upload-pack, git
>          upload-archive, cvs server, or a command in COMMAND_DIR.(…)

My advice would be (assuming you haven't done so already) to create a seperate user account for `git` alone, and have that account carry the appropriate public keys in `<git-home>/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Also, don't forget to remove the forced command from the public key(s) in question.
In addition, I recommend you set up `git`'s user account to use `git-shell` as it's default shell by modifying `/etc/passwd` like so:

> ```
> From "git:*:1000:1000:git systems account:/home/git:/bin/sh"
> To "git:*:1000:1000:git systems account:/home/git:/usr/local/bin/git-shell"
> ```

If `git-shell` is installed some place other than `/usr/local/bin`, `which git-shell` will tell you the exact path to follow.

Hope it helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note a complete answer, but you can take some clues from the [gitolite mirror-shell setup](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/mirroring.html#_setup_the_mirror_shell_on_each_server), where a [`gl-mirror-shell` script](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/gl-mirror-shell) is actually calling `git shell`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look here:

http://joey.kitenet.net/blog/entry/locking_down_ssh_authorized_keys/

This page suggests

`command="perl -e 'exec qw(git-shell -c), $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}'"`

to forward `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` to `git-shell`.  It works at my side.